# Split behaving weird in bash

Tags: bash, split, inotify

Trying to use split with inotifywait which basically splits the file when the file is created from ftp-server.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=/home/test-directory/incoming
SPLITTED=/home/test-directory/incoming/splitted
PROCESSED=/home/test-directory/incoming/processed
LOGFILE=/var/log/inotify-ftp.log

inotifywait -m -e create -e moved_to --format "%f" $TARGET \
        | while read FILENAME
                do
                        echo Detected $FILENAME >> $LOGFILE
                        echo Splitting $FILENAME >> $LOGFILE
                        split -d -l 1000 "$TARGET/$FILENAME" "$SPLITTED/$FILENAME"
                        #/usr/bin/split -d -l 1000 /home/test-directory/incoming/test-file.csv /home/test-directory/incoming/splitted/test-file.csv
                        mv "$TARGET/$FILENAME" "$PROCESSED/$FILENAME"
                        echo Completed splitting $FILENAME >> $LOGFILE
                done
```

So, the following code works fine when its executed separated. The above script is supposed to do the same thing but instead, it creates a first splitted file with couple hundred lines only.

```
#/usr/bin/split -d -l 1000 /home/test-directory/incoming/test-file.csv /home/test-directory/incoming/splitted/test-file.csv
```

Any idea, whats going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be because the file is zero-length when it is created. There is a race condition, where split figures out the size of the file, and decides how to split it up, while ftp-server is happily making it bigger all the time.

It would be wise to figure a mechanism where the split waits for the file to arrive completely before starting to read it. Typically, stat the file in a loop until it has not grown in the previous minute.

Comment: Use `close_write` instead of `create`

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558165/100397) the `create` event for `inotifywait` fires when the file has (just) been created, with no reference to content being added. Change the `create` event  to `close_write` so that you don't get a trigger until the file has been closed by your file transfer service:

```
inotifywait -m -e close_write -e moved_to --format "%f" "$TARGET"
```

You should also build in some error handling so that your process can differentiate between a completely transferred file and one that's been interrupted part way through. This might be checking the validity of the file contents, or by having the file transferred with a `tmp`suffix that's removed by the sender renaming the file on successful transfer, etc.

Finally, as good coding practice remember to double-quote your variables everywhere you use them.